# Query works fine via GUI, but returns generic error when try to run through Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, dapper

I have a query that runs just fine on MariaDB server via GUI, however as soon I will try to run through Dapper C# I will get an error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $
>   BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
>
> IF (@EndDate < NOW()) THEN
>       SET @GroupId = 3;
>   ' at line 1'

I am using regulard IDbConnection  i.e.

```
using (IDbConnection con = new MySqlConnection(SQLConfig.UI))
```

and to call the query:

```
return con.Query<MembershipDynamic.MembershipStatus>(sqlQuery, new{ @MembershipId = membershipId}).Single();
```

Same query works perfectly well with the same membershipId.

I have no idea why exactly same query wouldn't run via Dapper.

My connection string is regular one with only one extra parameter

```
AllowUserVariables=True
```

As the query is not a problem as runs fine through anything else, I am guessing that connection string is missing something ???

I also tried to set

```
 public MembershipsRepo()
    {
        DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new DapperExtensions.Sql.MySqlDialect();
    }
```

Here is the query. I've tried without DELIMITER on direct implementation of MySqlConnection but it will only return result for first select (???) ignoring the rest... The SQL is modified MS SQL procedure.

```
SET @TypeId = NULL;
SET @StartDate = NULL;
SET @EndDate = NULL;
SET @GroupId = NULL;
SET @Status = NULL;

SELECT @TypeId := TypeId, @StartDate := StartDate, @EndDate := EndDate
FROM Membership_Memberships
WHERE MembershipId = @MembershipId;

DELIMITER $
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC

IF (@EndDate < NOW()) THEN
SET @GroupId = 3;
SET @STATUS = 'Expired';
END IF;

IF (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Membership_Trials WHERE MembershipId = 
@MembershipId AND Active = 1 ) > 0  THEN
SET @GroupId = 4;
SET @Status = 'Trial';

ELSE
SELECT @GroupId := T.GroupType, @Status := T.Name FROM Membership_Types T 
WHERE T.Id = @TypeId;
-- RETURN  Select @GroupId, @Status;
END IF;

END $
DELIMITER ;

SELECT @GroupId, @Status;
```

Dapper / ADO.NET works fine with simple queries, but fails with a bit more advanced queries :/

***** EDIT

After some investigation it looks like MySQL is limited to 1 query per request, so pretty much not possible to write even a bit more advanced query :/ (with variables, as those are set by Select).

Only way is to create procs which I won't, or go back to Microsoft SQL or use some other SQL...

It would be a huge hit as I've invested almost 6 months into moving from SQL to MySQL :/ (architecture, replication, etc. etc.)

:(((((((((((

Comment: Can I perhaps see what the value of `sqlQuery` is or where it comes from? Also: note that not everything that works in a GUI tool *is the query*. For example, in SQL Server (example purely for my familiarity) people often think that `GO` is part of the SQL syntax - it isn't: the GUI (SSMS) / command-line tools themselves detect those tokens and does something with it - not actually sending them. If you use `GO` in an ADO.NET query on `SqlConnection`: it will fail. So I wonder if `DELIMETER $ BEGIN NOT ATOMIC` (from the question) is something similar.

Comment: BEGIN NOT ATOMIC is required to run IF statements in MySQL. I think that Dapper just won't properly work with bigger and more advanced queries (it was stored proc on MS SQL, but I want to ditch all stored procs).

I was reading around and looks like Dapper never was designed for that in a first place... I think that I might just create custom MySQL connector that I would be using for more advanced queries.


Query currently is written based on MySQL documentation.

Comment: dapper **doesn't care** (much) what your query is - it has very little interest in it - it can be small, large, simple, complex: not dapper's problem. It is the ADO.NET / MySqlClient layer that cares about that. So: does your query work in ADO.NET? If it doesn't: it won't work via dapper, because dapper's job is to demystify the ADO.NET API and provide utility features around that. But *the actual query* is ferried down to ADO.NET / MySqlClient.

Comment: I have tried to remove delimited / atomic, but result is 0 / null, even if variable set to specific value before return select.

Comment: "I have tried to remove delimited / atomic, but result is 0 / null, even if variable set to specific value before return select." since you haven't shown your query, it is very hard to comment on that

Comment: I've tried to run it via MySqlClient. Returns only first Select, instead going through it all :/ I don't know why SQL on MySQL runs so completely different than MS SQL :(

Comment: I think the key bit here: to find what is wrong, first try to get it working in ADO.NET (direct, not via dapper); I don't know enough about MySQL specifically to know what exactly the problem is, but I genuinely don't think that this particular scenario is dapper's doing. So: until it works on ADO.NET, it *can't* work on dapper (since dapper is a layer above that).

Comment: Well Dapper fails to run query that at least works in ADO.NET, so there is definitely an issue with Dapper. ADO.NET however also fails to run a query as I would run it on Linux server :/ So this is a tier issue. Runs fine on every SQL client, fails to up to some point on ADO.NET, fails completely on Dapper. Of course it fails with more advanced queries (start with IF statements)

Comment: I'll be happy to investigate the dapper part, but I'm *not* a MySql expert, so really I'd need a minimal repro that I can run and play with (context: I'm the primary dapper author/maintainer)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the code, but looks like MySQL team made a brilliant decision and you simply cannot run more > 1 select / query per query, so looks like this might not be possible ? (weird, very weird )

Comment: @Mike Author of MySqlConnector https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/ (alternative OSS MySQL .NET client) here: I was not familiar with MariaDB's `BEGIN NOT ATOMIC` block syntax but it should be possible to support. It will be easiest when the new command batching API https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35135 is designed, as that will sidestep the whole `DELIMITER` problem. (MySqlConnector can ship with a custom `MySqlBatch` implementation without needing it to be added to .NET Framework.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like we've lost few months of work.

MySQL is a not something that can replace Microsoft SQL.

Basically stored procedures will return all selects (and to join / process all cases etc. IT HAS to do a lot of selects / joins / if's).

Unfortunately this is a deal breaker as it would result returning 100's of MB of unnecessary data and break whole platform. (currently running on Microsoft SQL)